# How to make helper application communicate with XPC Services in main bundle

Tags: swift, cocoa, xpc

I have made a osx application contains a normal app, a login item which stored in 'Contents/Library/LoginItems' directory and a XPC Service stored in 'XPC Services' directory.

My main application can communicated with XPC Service like below.

```
let connection = NSXPCConnection(serviceName: "me.wanyi.xxx-XPCService")
```

It works fine.

But the login agent application can't work. It reported it can't communicate with the helper application. I thought it couldn't locate the XPC service.

I found it did work after I embed the XPC Service binary into the agent's bundle. But there will be two xpc binary bundles in the same bundle. I think maybe this is not an elegant solution.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Daniel No, I have no solution for now.

Comment: Are your apps sandboxed? Maybe you have to activate Application Group in the capabilities section of Xcode.

Comment: Yes, it is sandboxed. Already used application group. It seems app can only make launchd service loading XPC services which must be contained in app's own bundle. So helper app can't load the XPC service outside itself.

Comment: From everything I have read now, it looks like you are right. But if anyone knows more, please delight us. :)

Comment: @morphinewan did you find a solution?